# Rudin Principles of Mathematical Analysis Proposition 1.18e

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin's, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*

Proposition 1.18
.
.
.
.
e) If 0 < x < y then 0 < 1/y < 1/x.

Proof:
If y > 0 and v $\leq$ 0, then yv $\leq$ 0. But y $\cdot$ (1/y) = 1 > 0. Hence 1/y > 0.
Likewise, 1/x > 0. If we multiply both sides of the inequality x < y by the positive quantity (1/x)(1/y), we obtain 1/y < 1/x.

Now the part I fail to understand is the placement of the very first sentence. This may seem odd but the introduction of the v seems to be out of place and it's placement in this proof seems arbitrary.

I realize this may seem stupid to ask, but could someone please explain to me why this is in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its there like a multiplication property of the reals. For if $\frac{1}{y} \leq 0$, then by the property, for $v = \frac{1}{y} \leq 0$, $y\cdot \frac{1}{y} \leq 0$, but $y\cdot \frac{1}{y} = 1> 0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

It's being used as a vehicle to prove that $\frac{1}{y} > 0$.

Statement: If $y > 0 $ and $v \leq 0$ then $yv \leq 0$.

Contrapositive: If $yv > 0$ then $v > 0$ or $y \leq 0$.

Using the contrapositive with $v = \frac{1}{y}$ proves that $\frac{1}{y} > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Rudin is bringing in $v$ to show that if $y>0$, then $1/y>0$. To see this, let $y>0$. For any vector $v\leq0$, it follows that $vy\leq 0$. But now $y*1/y=1>0$. Therefore $1/y$ CANNOT be less than or equal to zero. Thus $1/y>0$. Does this help?